# Multiplication of matrices by dynamic memory allocation and void functions

Tags: c

I was writing a code for assignment, the code compiles but it doesn't run successfully.
It successfully functions till taking input matrices then it shows error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int r1, r2, c1, c2, **mat1, **mat2, **mat3, i, j, t;
void check(int c1, int r2);
void input();
void inputDisplay();
void multiplication(int **mat1,int **mat2);
void displayOutput(int **mat3);


int main()
{
    printf("enter the dimensions of first matrix\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &r1, &c1);
    printf("enter the dimensions of second mateix\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &r2, &c2);

    check(c1, r2);

    mat1 = (int **)malloc(r1*sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0; i<c1; i++)
    {
        mat1[i] =  (int *)malloc(c1*sizeof(int));
    }
    mat2 = (int **)malloc(r2*sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0; i<c2; i++)
    {
        mat2[i] = (int *)malloc(c2*sizeof(int));
    }
    mat3 = (int **)malloc(r1*sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0; i<c2; i++)
    {
        mat3[i] = (int *)malloc(c2*sizeof(int));
    }

    input();
    inputDisplay();
    multiplication(mat1, mat2);
    displayOutput(mat3);

    return 0;
}

void check(int c1, int r2)
{
    if(c1 != r2)
    {
        printf("these two matrices are not compatible for multiplication");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void input()
{
    printf("enter first matrix\n");
    for(i=0; i < r1; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c1; j++)
        {
            printf("value of %d row and %d column:", i + 1, j +1);
            scanf("%d", &mat1[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("enter second matrix\n");
    for(i=0; i<r2; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c2; j++)
        {
            printf("value of %d row and %d column:", i + 1, j +1);
            scanf("%d", &mat2[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void inputDisplay()
{
    printf("first matrix is:");
    for(i=0; i<r1; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0; j<c1; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", mat1[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\nsecond matrix is:");
    for(i=0; i<r2; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0; j<c2; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", mat2[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void multiplication(int **mat1, int **mat2)
{
    for(i=0; i<r1; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c2; j++)
        {
            mat3[i][j] = 0;
            for(t = 0; t < c1; t++);
            {
                mat3[i][j] += mat1[i][t]*mat2[t][j];
            }
        }
    }

}

void displayOutput(int **mat3)
{
    printf("resultant matrix is:");
    for(i=0; i<r1; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0; j<c2; j++)
        {
          printf("%d\t", mat3[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

After taking input matrices it shows
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)  -or-  0 as resultant matrix (which is false)
-or-  some garbage value as resultant matrix

Sample input:
rows and columns of both input matrices are 2.
all the elements in both input matrices are 1.

Comment: Please provide the exact input that reproduces the bug.

Comment: It would be more convenient to debug if a sample input is provided.

Comment: SIGSEGV on this line `mat3[i][j] += mat1[i][t]*mat2[t][j];`.

Comment: If you've learned about structures, you should use them to encapsulate your matrices.  Having global variables with the same names as function parameters tends to lead to confusion.  You should either pass 3 matrices to `multiplication()` or none — and none would be more consistent with the other code (but 3 pointers to matrix structures would be better coding style).  Similarly with `displayOutput()`.  Avoid global variables whenever possible.

Comment: @asuka: No, [xing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2669042/xing) has a valid point.  You only get away with what's written if you're processing square matrices.  Since your matrices are all 2x2, this isn't biting you yet — it will when you start to process non-square matrices.

Comment: Note that one problem with using global variables is that you have three copies of the printing code and 2 copies of the data entry code where you only need one of each.  If you created the functions properly, you'd be able to use one function called three times to print the three matrices; you'd pass the name as a string (to identify which matrix is being printed, and the size and the pointer to the data.  You also need code to free the matrices; again, one function should be used three times with the matrix size and pointer to data being passed to the function.  Or use structures, again.

Comment: _Side note:_ As others have mentioned, your `malloc` calls for a matrix need a fix. The bug is replicated in _three_ places. Better to use a _function_ to do the allocation and fix the [three] bugs in one place: `int ** matalloc(int r,int c) { int **mat;  mat = malloc(r * sizeof(int *)); for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) mat[i] = malloc(c * sizeof(int));  return mat; }` Then, replace the allocation code in `main` with: `mat1 = matalloc(r1,c1); mat2 = matalloc(r2,c2); mat3 = matalloc(r1,c1);`

Comment: Note that reliable code would check that every allocation succeeds.  Library code would release any already allocated memory if memory allocation fails partway through allocating a matrix.  That's fiddly, but necessary in professional, reliable code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a `;` is added at the line `for(t = 0; t < c1; t++);`. The intended

```
        for(t = 0; t < c1; t++)
        {
            mat3[i][j] += mat1[i][t]*mat2[t][j];
        }
```

becomes

```
        for(t = 0; t < c1; t++);
        {
            mat3[i][j] += mat1[i][t]*mat2[t][j];
        }
```

which is equal to

```c
t = c1;
mat3[i][j] += mat1[i][t]*mat2[t][j];
```

and finally `mat3[i][j] += mat1[i][c1]*mat2[c1][j];`, which causes the segment fault.

What's more, [xing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2669042/xing) pointed out that there is also a problem in the allocation process.

```
mat1 = (int **)malloc(r1*sizeof(int *));
for(i=0; i<c1; i++)
{
    mat1[i] =  (int *)malloc(c1*sizeof(int));
}
mat2 = (int **)malloc(r2*sizeof(int *));
for(i=0; i<c2; i++)
{
    mat2[i] = (int *)malloc(c2*sizeof(int));
}
mat3 = (int **)malloc(r1*sizeof(int *));
for(i=0; i<c2; i++)
{
    mat3[i] = (int *)malloc(c2*sizeof(int));
}
```

which should be

```
mat1 = (int **)malloc(r1*sizeof(int *));
for(i=0; i<r1; i++)
{
    mat1[i] =  (int *)malloc(c1*sizeof(int));
}
mat2 = (int **)malloc(r2*sizeof(int *));
for(i=0; i<r2; i++)
{
    mat2[i] = (int *)malloc(c2*sizeof(int));
}
mat3 = (int **)malloc(r1*sizeof(int *));
for(i=0; i<r1; i++)
{
    mat3[i] = (int *)malloc(c2*sizeof(int));
}
```

---

With a debugger like `gdb`, it is revealable that there is a SIGSEGV at line `mat3[i][j] += mat1[i][t]*mat2[t][j];`.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555555871 in multiplication (mat1=0x555555559ac0, mat2=0x555555559b20)
    at m.c:107
107                 mat3[i][j] += mat1[i][t]*mat2[t][j];
```

Then, `print t` outputs that current value of t is 2, which is out of range. With this information it is easier to locate the problem.

Comment: Ok, but tell what should I do. I'm a beginner at programming.

Comment: @NickGz: remove the superfluous and erroneous semicolon.  And deal with any other problems highlighted in the comments to the question.